# Python 2.5 zlib trouble

Tags: python, google-app-engine, zlib

I am trying to deploy an app on google app engine using bottle, a 
micro-framework, similar to flask. I am running on ubuntu which comes 
with python 2.7 installed but GAE needs version 2.5, so I installed 
2.5. I then realized I didn't use make altinstall so I may have a 
default version problem now. But my real problem is that when I try to 
use the gae server to test locally I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/opt/google/appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 77, in <module> 
    run_file(__file__, globals()) 
  File "/opt/google/appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 73, in run_file 
    execfile(script_path, globals_) 
  File "/opt/google/appengine/google/appengine/tools/ 
dev_appserver_main.py", line 156, in <module> 
    from google.appengine.tools import dev_appserver 
  File "/opt/google/appengine/google/appengine/tools/ 
dev_appserver.py", line 94, in <module> 
    import zlib
```

ImportError: No module named zlib

Can you help me with this?

Comment: It's a builtin module. Are you running a standard install of Python?

Answer (score 1):

How did you build Python 2.5?  If you built it from sources yourself, there's a good possibility the `zlib` module didn't get built because the necessary libraries and header files weren't installed on your system.

On Ubuntu, you need (I think) the `zlib1g-dev` package.

This will be true for a variety of other modules as well (for example, without the appropriate OpenSSL development libraries/headers in place, you won't get the `ssl` module either).

Someone may also have a `python2.5` package for your version of Ubuntu (although neither Natty or Maverick appear to have one in the official repositories).

Answer (score 0):

Before figuring out that using a post-2.5 Python worked just fine as long as you didn't use any post-2.5 language features or packages (or additions to package), I wrote up a walkthrough for building 2.5 for Ubuntu [here](http://www.davewsmith.com/blog/2010/google-app-engine-sdk-on-ubuntu-10-04). It includes the bit you need for zlib.

I'm now happily developing on Ubuntu using Python 2.6.5 (with SDK 1.5.4).